# CSS - Set div width equal to that of its "great-grandparent"

Tags: javascript, css, megamenu

I have found that setting the width of a div to 100% will make it's width the same as its parent but is it possible (maybe using CSS selectors) to set it equal to a parent 3 levels above? I am trying to make a mega menu like this: http://www.thenorthface.com/en_US/index.html
where I am trying to make the div the same size as the nav bar.

I have also tried just using class names and using javascript to set the div width. There are no errors in the console so I think my CSS might be overriding it although I have no set width values.

```
var navbarwidth = document.getElementById('nav-width').offsetWidth;
var megadropdown = document.getElementById('menu1');
megadropdown.style.width = navbarwidth;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just put the div inside of its great grandparent and then open it with javascript?

i.e.

```
<nav-bar>
   <drop-downs>
       <drop-down-1>
       <drop-down-2>
   </drop-downs>
   <menus>
       <menu-item1>
       <menu-item2>
   </menus>
</nav-bar>
```

And make it so that when drop-down-1 is clicked, it displays menu-item-1

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you have the mega_drop down under your nav-bar and set them both to the same width responsively like this..

```
<nav>
  <ul>
     <li id="link1">Link One<li>
     <li id="link2">Link Two<li>
     <li id="link3">Link Three<li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="menu-container">
  <div id="menu-1">
  <div id="menu-2">
  <div id="menu-3">
</div>
```

Then your css would be:

```
nav{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu-container div{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: none;
```

}

```
ul.li#linkx:hover #menu-x{
    display: block;
```

}

This way you don't need any js and you can also add media queries to change the overall size of the mega-menu for different sized screens. It does require more css though as you have to write hover states for each Nav Bar link.

Comment: So the only problem with this is that you can't use CSS to make elements appear that aren't children of the hovered element. I'm trying to get it to work in the same strategy but using javascript to show or hide.

Comment: Sorry about that @sullivaa, you can in fact make elements appear that are not children of the :hover element. But you need to add a + into your CSS like this:

ul.li#linkx:hover + #menu-x{